# Como hacer que typescript reconozca una prototype de vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Para simplificar el uso de axios en mi aplicacion, use una prototype para declararlo globablemente.

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URI,
  withCredentials: true
});

Vue.prototype.$http = instance;
```

Hasta aca no hay ningun problema, el problema surge al usarlo en cualquier componente

```
import vue from 'vue'; <- agregado solo para ver si solucionaba el problema
import { Component, Vue, Watch} from 'vue-property-decorator';
.....
this.$http.get('url')
.then(Response => )
```

Este código, indica con razón para typescript:

> "Property '$http' does not exist on type 'YourComponent'."

Entonces, como se hace para que typescript reconozca eso y no ande protestando que no sabe que es?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la [documentación oficial tienes cómo hacerlo](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins): Tomas la declaración de la clase y la *aumentas*:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// Specify a file with the types you want to augment
// Vue has the constructor type in types/vue.d.ts
declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  // 3. Declare augmentation for Vue
  interface Vue {
    $myProperty: string
  }
}
```

Por lo que deberías poder hacer algo como

```
import {AxiosStatic} from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  export interface Vue   {
    $http: AxiosStatic;
  }
}
```

###Explicación:

En Typescript es equivalente hacer esta declaración

```
interface X {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}
```

Que esta otra:

```
interface X {
  a: string;
}

//... más código

interface X {
  b: number;
}
```

Comment: Hay que agrear eso a un archivo de .d.ts para que lo vea. En mi caso, y por simplificacion, lo agregue en shims-tsx.d.ts, pero seguramente se pueda agregar a uno mejor.